# Can people near you see what you're seeing and hear what you are hearing in google glass?

Tags: google-glass

I'm just wondering how much "local physical privacy" does google glass provide to the wearer, comparing it with mobile phones.

Many people are worried about privacy when it comes to google glass (and rightly so) because it can be an invasion to privacy from google. But I think this new wearable device might also provide augmented physical privacy to the wearer when compared with today's mobile phones with big sized screens.

Can anyone with real hands-on experience with google glasses can answer this? Another related privacy-related question would be how noisy can the "Bone Conduction Transducer" be to the people around you, how much can the people near you hear it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about privacy issues related to the usage of Google Glass, and not about programming for/with Google Glass.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that Google Glass augments physical privacy.

It is very difficult for people around you to hear what Glass is saying to you. In dead silence and close proximity, people may be able to hear that Glass is outputting audio in the form of soft unintelligible noises. I would say that in a setting with a moderate level of ambient noise and personal space (like an office) no one would notice.

The screen is also a welcome change in privacy. It's easy to look over someone's shoulder when their focus is directed to a mobile phone or tablet device. While using Glass, it's difficult for another person to make out what you're viewing due to the size of the screen. Something about the screen being next to your eye also deters people from staring too hard. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

I think that this is an important part of Glass that people haven't noticed that much. And this is most probably going to be one of the reasons why people are not going to use that much the "voice" interface.

A keyboard is much more private than talking aloud. I envision a near future where glass users stop buying big screen mobile phones and start buying phones with a big physical keyboard and a small screen, if any. Glass is your screen! Phones will be much cheaper, lightweight and batteries will last more. Maybe I should do a kickstarter with the idea?

Answer (score 0):

If someone near you looked closely at the display, they might make out roughly what you are looking at. Externally it's a reversed image about 1mm x 1mm. I can see, for example, when it shows the battery charging icon, when I'm not wearing it. However I could not read text.

Someone putting their ear near yours can probably make out a bit of the audio. Glass comes with an earpiece you can use though which would foreclose that possibility.